# Make a div appear parallel to anchor tag - onclick

Tags: jquery, css, html, html-table

I have a table with one action column having anchor tags for each row. I want to populate and display a **same div** on each of the anchor click.

I am able to do this, but I want that div to be appear parallel to that anchor tag which is clicked to display.

Problem : I have created everything and its working fine but I am unable to position it. Currently it is appearing on top and when I click the anchor tag at the last row at bottom of the page, the div appears again at top but I want it to appear right there parallel to that bottom most anchor.

Here is the jsFiddle for depicting the sample.
http://jsfiddle.net/8bLHF/

```
<div id="myDiv"><p>Hello</p></div>
<table border="1" cellpadding="10">
 <tr>
   <th>Action</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td><a id="anchor" href="#">1</a></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td><a id="anchor" href="#">2</a></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td><a id="anchor" href="#">3</a></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td><a id="anchor" href="#">4</a></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td><a id="anchor" href="#">5</a></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Please help

Comment: you can use .offset() to do this
http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Comment: have you been here --> this http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8bLHF/1/)

First of all make your `id="anchor"` to a class `class="anchor`".

```
$(document).on('click', '.anchor', function (e) {
    var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coordinates
    var mousey = e.pageY + 10; //Get Y coordinates
    $('#myDiv')
        .css({
        top: mousey,
        left: mousex
    });
    $("#myDiv").fadeIn();
});

$(document).on('click', '#myDiv', function () {
    $("#myDiv").fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but i wanted to make it appear on the left side of the anchor tag.  What changes should i make? With this, my div gets hidden somewhere underneath and am not able to see it although click works fine.

Comment: just change the `e.pageX + whatEverUWant` and the `e.pageY + whatEverUWant` to make it appear on the left side.

Comment: perfect! Just what i wanted. Thank you so much! Also i was thinking to perform some jquery animation and used sliding function using toggle `slideToggle()` but the problem is, if a click one anchor, the div get displayed but when i click some other anchor tag, the div get toggled and i have to re-click again to make it display. How can i achieve this thing?

Comment: follow this link http://jsfiddle.net/8bLHF/8/  `$("#myDiv").stop().hide().slideToggle('fast');`

Answer (score 3):

Change your on click to the following.

```
$(document).on('click', '#anchor', function(e){
   $("#myDiv").offset({left:e.pageX,top:e.pageY});
   $("#myDiv").fadeIn();
});
```

This will change the div position to the mouse click. You can change this a bit to get the results you want but this might give you some idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/8bLHF/5/

First change anchor id to class.

```
$(document).on('click', '.anchor', function(){
    var p = $(this).parent('td');
    var position = p.position();
    $("#myDiv").css({
        'left':$('#myTable').width()+10 +'px', 
        'top':position.top+'px'
    });
    $("#myDiv").fadeIn();
});

$(document).on('click', '#myDiv', function(){
     $("#myDiv").fadeOut(); 
});
```